# Left-click doesn't work on web canvas being hosted in WPF WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, canvas, vis.js

I'm trying to present [vis.js](http://visjs.org) web page in my WPF using WebBrowser, the page presented successfully but I can left-click any of the items inside the canvas.

Mouse zoom is working as expected inside the canvas.

I wrote a simple project contains only 2 files:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser"></WebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser.Navigate("http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/configuration.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I added my registry the following key so my WPF process will use IE11:

> Key name: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\processName.exe
>   Type: REG_DWORD Value Data: 11000 (decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't answer your question directly but I'll give you some advice based on my experience, and that is: never use default wpf WebBrowser for anything even remotely serious. I tried to use it before many times for many different projects and *always* got some showstopper issue, no exceptions. And of course that is with IE11 (10,9 - I tried it many times as I said) emulation.

Look at your case for example. Not only canvas clicks do not work - whole page is completely destroyed. Sliders are messed up, if you try to choose a color - clicks again do not work, and many more issues on this *single page*.

So, don't bother with wpf WebBrowser and just use real browser, for example Chromium. I personally prefer [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) which has wpf binding to chromium. Just install their nuget package (CefSharp.WPF), then:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And

```
InitializeComponent();
webBrowser.Address = "http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/configuration.html";
```

And you page just displays as it should. Canvas clicks work, no styles are destoyed, color pickers work. In addition to all that, cefsharp browser control is *much* more flexible. You can call to\from javascript easily, intercept almost every event (resource load, redirections), you can disable javascript\images, even intercept requests and feed completely different data. And no need to fix registry on every client machine.

Note that if you would install CefSharp.WPF via package, it will require your project to have x86\x64 platform (does not work with AnyCPU). But you really *can* make it work with anyCPU with little effort, if you would have such requirement.

Comment: Thanks! it works, can you assist me how to make it work on AnyCPU?

Comment: I basically reference x64 version of target dlls in my development environment from my AnyCPU project, and when deploying to client - correct version (x64\x86) of cefsharp is downloaded and deployed. So the fact I reference x64 from AnyCPU doesn't hurt because on client always correct version of all libraries are present. You can also deploy both x64\x86 versions of CefSharp to the client and decide at runtime which version to use (using for example AssemblyResolve event of AppDomain).